# Jboss EAP 6.2 log4j.properties not logging output but creating log-file

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss-eap-6

Please help, as default our logs goes to server.log. however, I wanted to create a specific log for my application, when adding log4j.properties it only creates a log file (test/app.log) but not produces any output.

see log4j.properties below:

```
# LOG4J daily rolling log files configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=../test/app.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %t_%p  %C (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

my dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have also tried adding jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false in Jboss system properties.

Thanks

Comment: How are you logging in class file?

Comment: If you want to use log4j as a log manager you need to use log4j as your facade as well. If you're using slf4j you can use a logging-profile or a logging.properties to configure logging for your deployment.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this dependency as well

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```